# Programmatically add IBAction to UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, ibaction

I am trying to add an action to a UIButton, but keep getting an exception:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '[UIImageView addTarget:action:forControlEvents:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x595fba0'

Here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIImage *myIcon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Icon_Profile"];
    self.profileButton = (UIButton*)[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:myIcon];

    [self.profileButton addTarget:self action:@selector(profileButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    UIBarButtonItem *buttonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:profileButton] autorelease];

    NSArray *toolbarItems = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:buttonItem, nil];

    [self setToolbarItems:toolbarItems animated:NO];

    //[toolbarItems release];
    //[profileButton release];
}
```

Then I have this method in the same View controller:

```
-(void)profileButtonPressed:(id)sender{

}
```

And in the header I have

```
-(IBAction)profileButtonPressed:(id)sender;
```

What's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't cast a `UIImageView` object to `UIButton` and expect it to behave like a `UIButton`. Since you intend to create a `UIBarButtonItem`,  use `initWithImage:style:target:action:` to init it with an image.

```
UIBarButtonItem *buttonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:myIcon style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(profileButtonPressed:)] autorelease];
```

I think this is a better approach over creating a `UIButton` and assigning it as a custom view.

Answer (score 4):

You are casting an `UIImageView` to `UIButton` which does not respond to `addTarget:action:forControlEvents:`. Create an actual button and set image for different states by using `setBackgroundImage:forState:` or `setImage:forState:` of `UIButton`.

Answer (score 3):

Why are you casting a UIImageView into a button.

```
UIImage *myIcon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Icon_Profile"];
self.profileButton = [UIButton buttonWithStyle:UIButtonStyleCustom];
[self.profileButton setImage:myIcon forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.profileButton addTarget:self action:@selector(profileButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: setImage: or setImage:forState: ?

Answer (score 2):

This looks very wrong:

```
self.profileButton = (UIButton*)[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:myIcon];
```

A `UIImageView` is not a `UIButton`. You should `alloc` and `init` a proper `UIButton`, and then you can call

```
[self.profileButton setImage: myIcon forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 2):

Create your own button at first. And add action after:

```
UIImage *myIcon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Icon_Profile"];
UIButton *buttonPlay = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
buttonPlay.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20);
[buttonPlay setBackgroundImage:myIcon forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[buttonPlay addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPlayClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

And your selector should be like this

```
- (void)buttonPlayClick:(UIButton*)sender{
}
```

Now you can create custom bar item

```
UIBarButtonItem *buttonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:buttonPlay] autorelease];
```